# How to manage acquia website in Lamp environment?

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop, acquia-cloud

I know, there is Acquia dev desktop application available for Wamp and Mamp environment.

We have Lamp environment. But, we are not able to clone the website in linux environment.

I want to use the same or other interface for managing the Acquia application for Lamp environment.

Please guide.

Comment: Tutorials/guides for general topics don't suit Q+A, please ask a question about a specific problem as you encounter it, including all relevant details. Thanks

Comment: We have Lamp environment. But, we are not able to clone the website in linux environment.

Comment: That's not relevant to anything here. Please read the previous comment, the close reasons on this and your previous question, and the [help] to get a clear idea of why the questions you're asking aren't suitable for Drupal Q+A

Comment: Acquia is basically for the Drupal. I am facing this issue. I am not able to clone the site which is created on Acquia.com in linux environment.

Comment: I'm sure that's annoying, but that doesn't change what level of detail is required for questions on this site. It's not a support forum, it's not a tutorial or guide writing service, it's a Q+A site, with a very strict definition of what that means